# Graphql urql refetch every n seconds

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, urql

Im using Typescript, React- and graphql with the urql client library.

My Query looks something like this:

```
query objectId($id: Int!) {
  object(id: $id) {
      id
      name
      __typename
      }
  }
```

This is how I call the query:

```js
const [{ data }] = useObjectIdQuery({ variables: { id }, pause: !id });
```

**Question:**

How can i refetch every n seconds without reloading the page?

My backend reads JSON files and they update consistently.
Now I have looked into the documentation [here](https://formidable.com/open-source/urql/docs/api/core/), and also on a bunch of Stackoverflow and no-name sites.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the documentation provides a function for that. I built myself a hook to use it in the whole project for any query. Just becareful with the query parameter, it has to be the already build graphql `DocumentNode` as parameter.

You can import them like this for each Query:

```
import { ObjecIdDocument } from "../../graphql";
```

The graphql path may be different in your case.

This is the full `Hook`:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useQuery } from "urql";
import { DocumentNode } from "graphql";

const useRefreshingQuery = (variables: object, query: DocumentNode, delayInSec: number, pause: boolean) => {
    const [result, reexecuteQuery] = useQuery({
        query: query,
        variables: variables,
        pause: pause,
    });
    useEffect(() => {
        if (result.fetching) {
            return;
        }
        const timerId = setTimeout(() => {
            reexecuteQuery({ requestPolicy: "network-only" });
        }, delayInSec * 1000);

        return () => clearTimeout(timerId);
    }, [result.fetching, reexecuteQuery, variables]);
    return result;
};

export default useRefreshingQuery;
```

You can use the `Hook` like this:

```js
import { ObjecIdDocument } from "../../graphql"; 


const result = useRefreshingQuery({ id: UID }, ObjectIdDocument, 10, !UID);
```